# C# Controlling the number of times fired

Tags: c#, events

I'm probably over complicating this but I've been stuck and I find myself coding up really silly solutions to this issue anyway.

Here's the scenario.  I've got a stream of numbers coming in. 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,5,6 etc....

```
 private void NotifyAlert(int p)
    {
        EventHandler<DataEventArgs> handler = Value;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new DataEventArgs(p));
        }

    }



 if(x > 4)
 {
     NotifyAlert(x);  
     return;
 }
```

So what's happening is the event fires for the value  greater than 4, then 5, then 6...etc and in my event handler

```
 private static void ValueAlertHandler(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Message) > 4)
            {

                SendUpdate(e.message);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want is for it to only call the SendUpdate() once when the value is hit but it gets called for every value after that.
I know I'm missing something just not sure what.  Thank in advance guys.

EDIT: To clarify.  What I'd like for is the event to be raised when the number goes above 4 and call the SendUpdate() method once.  Then if the numbers fall under 4 and once again go back up above 4, to call the SendUpdate() once.  This process will repeat.

Comment: Are you saying that once you have called SendUpdate, you don't ever want to call it again?

Comment: @BillGregg Sorry to clear that up, I want it to call once for when the value is hit but not for any other value above it.  For example( x > 4 raise event called method) and if the stream of numbers goes under 4 then comes back again again raise event and call the method only once.

Comment: @Valmorgal: You might want to edit the original post to reflect your change in requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work, first, you'll need to remove the condition of "if (x > 4)" around the call to "NotifyAlert(x);".  You need the method to get called for all values, not just the ones greater than 4.

So instead of...

```
if(x > 4)
{
    NotifyAlert(x);  
    return;
}
```

... simply do ...

```
NotifyAlert(x);
```

This is an important first step.

Then you modify your event handler code like so:

```
private static bool isOver4 = false;    

private static void ValueAlertHandler(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(e.Message);
        if (x > 4)
        {
            if (!isOver4)
            {
                SendUpdate(e.message);
                isOver4 = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isOver4 = false;
        }
    }
}
```

(*) Note 1: You can also choose to move the entire logic out of the event handler, and put it around the call to NotifyAlert(x), as others have suggested.  However, since you are doing some concurrency control in the event handler (locking on 'locker'), then you probably want the tracking of the values to be done serially.  At least, that appears to be your intent.  In that case, the logic needs to happen inside the event handler.

(*) Note 2: I notice that your post is just a bit contradictory.  Your code indicates that the event starts firing when the value is greater than 4.  Yet, from your written explanation, we are led to believe that the event fires when the value is **equal to** or greater than 4.  Make sure to adjust the comparison to what your requirements really are.

Comment: I'll try using that and yes you are right there is some concurrency stuff happening in the SendUpdate() method.  I'll give this a shot.  Also I updated the post to show greater than 4.

Comment: If you found this answers useful, an accepted answer is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

```
private static bool _alertedAlready = false;

private static void ValueAlertHandler(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Message) > 4)
        {
            if (!_alertedAlready)
            {
                SendUpdate(e.message);
                _alertedAlready = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can rewrite this to look nicer in many ways, but the idea remains. You need an indication whether this is the first alert.

Comment: You can combine the ifs to `if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Message) > 4 && !_alertedAlready)`

Comment: @StuperUser True. I'd personally even prefer `if (_alertedAlready) return;` before the lock. As I said, you can make this look nicer in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it you only want the event to fire when the threshold is reached rather than have the event handler have to decide whether or not to handle the event by calling `SendUpdate`.

I'd set it up so that `NotifyAlert` is only called when it actually needs to be rather than having the event handler having to know more than it might need to.  For instance, does the event handler also have to know that the threshold is 4?  Currently, if you need to change the threshold you have to do it in multiple places.  For instance, you could do something like this:

```
Action<int> SendNotification = (p) => NotifyAlert(p);
Action<int> IgnoreValue = (p) -> {};
Action<int> Notify = SendNotification;

...

if(x > 4)
{
    Notify(x);
    Notify = IgnoreValue;
    return;
}
else
{
    Notify = SendNotification;
    return;
}
```

This is more verbose than simply using a boolean to decide whether or not to fire the event, but it also allows for flexibility - you may want to do something internally anytime the value is higher than the threshold, but not necessarily fire the event.

With a flag:
    private bool alreadyAboveThreshold = false;

```
...

if(x > 4 && !alreadyAboveThreshold)
{
    NotifyAlert(x);
    alreadyAboveThreshold = true;
    return;
}
else
{
    alreadyAboveThreshold = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes I'd prefer the Event to fire once.  How would I go about doing that? :)

Comment: The code I put in my answer would work since it'd only call `NotifyAlert` the first time `x` exceeds the threshold.  It then sets the `Notify` action to a function that does nothing.  So the next time `x` exceeds the threshold, the call to `Notify(x)` calls the empty function.  If `x` falls below the threshold then `Notify` is set back to `NotifyAlert`, causing the event to be fired again the next time `x` exceeds the threshold.

Comment: I added example code using a flag rather than separate `Action<T>` instances to my answer.